# Deciding the order of operations without changing the code

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a C# method.

```
  void SomeMethod()
{
Console.WriteLine("A");
Console.WriteLine("B");
Console.WriteLine("A");
Console.WriteLine("B);
}
```

I want the output as 
A
A
B
B

I can only add some code lines above or below the existing lines but cannot change the sequence. How the threading should be implemented to acheive the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the first `"B"` output into a thread and run the thread only after the second `"A"` is printed:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("A");
    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    });
    Console.WriteLine("A");
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
    Console.WriteLine("B");
}
```